# java.nio.file can not copy files

Tags: java, groovy

Very simple file copy, both directories are exist, got below message:

Code--

```
  import java.nio.file.Files;
  import java.nio.file.Paths;
  import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

  Files.copy(
      Paths.get("/u/isciw2/reposi1/ISCIW batch/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml"), 
      Paths.get(" /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW  batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml"),
      REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

> ERROR-- Caught: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: 
>   /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW
>   batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: 
>   /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW
>   batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml
>     at
>   groovy_script_3470154301378281065.run(groovy_script_3470154301378281065.groovy:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UNIX, copy and paste your paths into commands like:

```
$ ls "/PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml"
```

... ensuring that the quotes and the spaces appear exactly as they do in your Java.

I would expect you to get an error response like:

```
ls: cannot access /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml: No such file or directory
```

... in which case Java and `ls` agree: this file doesn't exist.

Now find the actual file, and adjust the `ls` command until it doesn't error. Once it works, you can copy/paste the correct path into your Java.

As a short cut (assuming the base of the path is correct), you could find candidate correct paths with something like:

```
$ find /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd -name packageManifest.xml
```

... or even, on many systems:

```
$ locate packageManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

My bet would be the `NoSuchFileException` is thrown correctly, so you should double-check the paths used. In the second path there are some suspicious-looking spaces:

```
 " /PXAS61/usr/lpp/ucd/V6.2.1/var/work/ISCIW  batch/546b3d10-0256-4bcd-9d3c-504ca31714d5/20170821-3927/packageManifest.xml"
```